# Is a previous year Roth IRA contribution possible since I have to resubmit the previous years taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira, contribution

I've been out of the country for the past couple years. I called the IRS this year and found out my last years tax return was rejected because I electronically signed it.

People have told me you can always contribute up until the tax deadline, so my question is since I have to refile for 2013 can I also make a retroactive contribution for 2013 since I have to refile that years taxes anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The electronic rejection didn't change the due date of your return and the following code sections still apply.

> [§ 408A(c)(7)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/408A#c_7) ->  [§219(f)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/219#f_3)
>
> **(3) Time when contributions deemed made**
>   For purposes of this section, a taxpayer shall be deemed to have made a contribution to an
>   individual retirement plan on the last day of the preceding taxable
>   year if the contribution is made on account of such taxable year and
>   is made not later than the time prescribed by law for filing the
>   return for such taxable year (not including extensions thereof).